# Sap UI5 XML view (Fiori)

Tags: xml, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have been trying to create a simple `Fiori` application using `XML` views. I need help in following points:

1. Navigate to another view using `navTo()` onclick of button.
2. Create a table (always get error "failed to load resource").
3. Fit little big content in one view.

Please note that I am using `NWDS` and I have `SAPUI5` library of version 1.22.9

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: This question is too broad, unclear, and shows zero research effort which hasn't changed since 2016. SO should not be simply taken as a code providing platform.

Answer (score 0):

For navigating to other page, you can write a function with below code and invoke it on your button's press event:

```
this.oRouter.navTo("pagename"); // you will have to define the pagename in components
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply  but please explain how to define pagename in component ? As i'm getting error as below
"Cannot read property 'navTo' of undefined sap.ui.controller.handleEvent"

Comment: hi, there is a pretty good documentation on it:
https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/95/8ead51e2e94ab8bcdc90fb7e9d53d0/content.htm

You can also refer below example :

    viewPath: "com.sap.fiori.aribamobile.shoppingcart.view",
        fullScreenPageRoutes: {
            "landingPage": {
                "pattern": "",
                "view": "R1",
                "viewLevel": 1
            },
            "homepage": {
                "pattern": "homepage",
                "view": "S1",
                "viewLevel": 1
            },

Answer (score -1):

1 - check :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5BCf-j6GLA

2 - post your xml code here to check mistakes.

3 - Use JsonModel, see little example below:

Create and set jsonModel on onInit function of firstViewController.

```
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

            var oData = {

                process: "nrProcess",
                items: [{

                    matdesc: "content",
                    qtd: "content",
                    um: "content",
                    util: "content",
                    setor: "content",
                    obs: "content"

                }]
            };

            oModel.setData(oData);
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```